# Dont let excel open the file if it is already opened

Tags: .net, excel

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open Method 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open(VS.80).aspx

This method opens a dialog window if the file is already opened, asking the user if he wants to open as read-only or not open (the method returns null if user chose to not open)

I wish to block this dialog and open the file only with read/write permissions

Answer (score 2):

Does

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

help?